# Creating endless scrolling in RecyclerView like modern google calendar app has

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I would like to make app with one fragment very similar to plan section in modern google calendar app (https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnREL.png).

How can I achieve endless scrolling in both direction, loading items asyncly, like google calendar does? I tried using RecyclerView but I don't know how to separate items (in google cal events) to sections like day, week or month and how to achieve endless up scrolling.

I also tried to find google calendar source, but I found only this git repo https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calendar, that's only built-in android calendar app source, not the modern one with material design. So I suppose that it isn't open source, is it?

Comment: May be this [link guide you](https://github.com/pwittchen/InfiniteScroll) for endless scrolling

Comment: Hint :: What google calendar do is when you scroll it go to server and take the data and show you in the list when you again scroll it do same thing.It is similar thing which any Purchasing website do if you are see the product.

Comment: @AndyDeveloper Thanks, but what about endless scrolling up? And what about sections like day or month? How can Recycler recycle Views if there can be 3 events on some day while 10 on some other? Should I use something like SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter or should my RecyclerView items be days instead of events?

Comment: I'd definitely use SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter or the like. If you roll out your own solution remember you can have different types of rows, with different type IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually 3 ways to achieve this, one of which is like the library linked earlier:

- When you encounter the end of the list, start loading more and show a loading indicator

or

- Load items in advance when the user scrolls close enough to the end, show a loading indicator if the user reaches the end too fast

or (my favorite)

- Generate X amount of dummy (empty) list items in the end and replace them with the loaded items when the user has scrolled enough, show that they are loading while they're in the dummy state - this method enables a "true" endless scroll

Comment: Thanks, but what about endless scrolling up, like into history. How can I load items before? Can they have negative position?

Comment: This works in both directions, you just need to know the range you have currently loaded and put a loading indicator in both ends, the load more in the end the user is scrolling towards